# Prolog addition on wrapped values

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I wrote a test program with bindings (facts) between atoms and numbers.

```prolog
bind(a, 3).
bind(b, 4).
bind(c, 5).
```

As part of a toy interpreter, I want to be able to perform additions on these atoms using Prolog's native arithmetic operators. For instance, I want to be able to run this query:

```prolog
% val(X) is the value bound to X
?- X is val(a) + val(b).
X = 7.
```

However, I'm struggling to find a way to allow this addition. My first approach would have been this one:

```prolog
% val(X, Y): Y is the value bound to X
val(X, Y) :- bind(X, Y).

% Make val an arithmetic function
:- arithmetic_function(val/1).
```

However, `arithmetic_function/1` is no longer part of Prolog (or at least SWI-Prolog says it's deprecated), so I can't use it. Then I believed the best solution would be to overload the `+` operator to take this into account:

```prolog
% val(X, Y): Y is the value bound to X
val(val(X), Y) :- bind(X, Y).

% Overload the + operator
+(val(_X, XVal), val(_Y, YVal)) :- XVal + YVal.
```

But here I've got my syntax all messed up because I don't really know how to overload a native arithmetic operation. When I type in the sample query from before, SWI-Prolog says ``` ERROR: Arithmetic: ``val(a)' is not a function ```.

Would you have hints about a possible solution or a better approach or something I missed?

Answer (score 4):

From the docs, I tought you should use [function_expansion](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=function_expansion/3)/3.
But I'm unable to get it to work, instead, [goal_expansion](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=goal_expansion/2) could do, but isn't very attractive... for instance, if you save the following definitions in a file bind.pl (just to say)

```
:- module(bind, [test/0]).

:- dynamic bind/2.

bind(a, 3).
bind(b, 4).
bind(c, 5).

% :- multifile user:goal_expansion/2.
user:goal_expansion(val(X), Y) :- bind(X, Y).
user:goal_expansion(X is Y, X is Z) :- expand_goal(Y, Z).
user:goal_expansion(X + Y, U + V) :- expand_goal(X, U), expand_goal(Y, V).

test :-
     X is val(a) + val(b), writeln(X).
```

and consult it, you can run your test:

```
?- test.
7
```

**edit**

after Paulo suggestion, here is an enhanced solution, that should work for every *binary* expression.

```
user:goal_expansion(X is Y, X is Z) :- expr_bind(Y, Z).

expr_bind(val(A), V) :- !, bind(A, V).
expr_bind(X, Y) :-
     X =.. [F, L, R],  % get operator F and Left,Right expressions
     expr_bind(L, S),  % bind Left expression
     expr_bind(R, T),  % bind Right expression
     Y =.. [F, S, T].  % pack bound expressions back with same operator
expr_bind(X, X).       % oops, I forgot... this clause allows numbers and variables
```

having defined *user* as target module for goal_expansion, it works on the CLI:

```
?- R is val(a)*val(b)-val(c).
R = 7.
```

**edit**

now, let's generalize to some other arithmetic operators, using the same skeleton expr_bind uses for binary expressions:

```
user:goal_expansion(X, Y) :-
     X =.. [F,L,R], memberchk(F, [is, =<, <, =:=, >, >=]),
     expr_bind(L, S),
     expr_bind(R, T),
     Y =.. [F, S, T].
```

and unary operators (I cannot recall no one apart minus, so I show a simpler way than (=..)/2):

```
...
expr_bind(-X, -Y) :- expr_bind(X, Y).
expr_bind(X, X).
```

Now we get

```
?- -val(a)*2 < val(b)-val(c).
true.
```

Comment: Best to only use a `user:goal_expansion/2` clause for `is/2` goals and call an auxiliary predicate to expand the `is/2` second argument to prevent any unintended expansions. It's an attractive solution in that it keeps `is/2` for evaluation and thus doesn't require extra code if numbers are also used in expressions. It's not a very portable solution but that may or may not be an issue for the OP.

Comment: @PauloMoura: thanks so much, much better after your suggestion. Could ask if you have a clue about using function_expansion/3 ?

Comment: Note that you need one more clause for _unary_ operators so that we can write e.g. `-val(b)` or `abs(val(c))`. The `function_expansion/3` name is a bit misleading as it does **sub-term** expansion. I don't think  it would provide any advantage over your solution as it would apply broadly instead of just the second argument of `is/2`. Btw, we may also need additional clauses for the arithmetic comparison operators such that we can write e.g. `val(b) =< val(c)`.

Comment: A limitation that is worth mentioning in your answer is that the term-expansion mechanism applies at compile time and at the top-level. Runtime dynamically generated expressions will not be expanded. The solution I posted doesn't have this limitation as it's not based on term-expansion.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it is using Logtalk parametric objects (Logtalk runs on SWI-Prolog and 11 other Prolog systems; this makes this solution highly portable). The idea is to define each arithmetic operation as a parametric object that understands an `eval/1` message. First we define a protocol that will be implemented by the objects representing the arithmetic operations:

```
:- protocol(eval).

    :- public(eval/1).

:- end_protocol.
```

The basic parametric object understands `val/1` and contains the `bind/2` table:

```
:- object(val(_X_), implements(eval)).

    eval(X) :-
         bind(_X_, X).

    bind(a, 3).
    bind(b, 4).
    bind(c, 5).

:- end_object.
```

I exemplify here only the implementation for arithmetic addition:

```
:- object(_X_ + _Y_, implements(eval)).

    eval(Result) :-
        _X_::eval(X), _Y_::eval(Y),
        Result is X + Y.

:- end_object.
```

Sample call (assuming the entities above are saved in an `eval.lgt` file):

```
% swilgt
...
?- {eval}.
% [ /Users/pmoura/Desktop/eval.lgt loaded ]
% (0 warnings)
true.

?- (val(a) + val(b))::eval(R).
R = 7.
```

This can be an interesting solution if you plan to implement more functionality other than expression evaluation. E.g. a similar solution but for symbolic differentiation of arithmetic expressions can be found at:

https://github.com/LogtalkDotOrg/logtalk3/tree/master/examples/symdiff

This solution will also work in the case of runtime generated expressions (term-expansion based solutions usually only work at source file compile time and at the top-level).

If you're only interested in expression evaluation, Capelli's solution is more compact and retains `is/2` for evaluation. It can also be made more portable if necessary using Logtalk's portable term-expansion mechanism (but note the caveat in the previous paragraph).

Answer (score 1):

This is perhaps not exactly what I was looking for, but I had an idea:

```prolog
compute(val(X) + val(Y), Out) :-
  bind(X, XVal),
  bind(Y, YVal),
  Out is XVal + YVal.
```

Now I can run the following query:

```
?- compute(val(a) + val(c), Out).
Out = 8.
```

Now I need to define `compute` for every arithmetic operation I'm interested in, then get my interpreter to run expressions through it.

Comment: The solution I posted does essentially that, using `eval/1` in a similar way to your `compute/2`  predicate.